# How to map a vector into actix-web client requests and run them sequentially?

Tags: rust, future, rust-actix

I have a vector and I want to make multiple requests and get vector of values. Something like:

```
use actix_web::client;
let nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
let values = nums.map(|num| {
    client::ClientRequest::get("http://example.com".to_owned() + &num);
});
```

And I will get `[1, 4, 9]`.

Said another way:

```
fn question_data(id: &str) -> Box<Future<Item = Question, Error = actix_web::error::Error>> {
    let f = std::fs::read_to_string("auth_token").unwrap();
    let token = f.trim();
    Box::new(
        client::ClientRequest::get("https://example.com/api/questions/".to_owned() + id)
            .header(
                actix_web::http::header::AUTHORIZATION,
                "Bearer ".to_owned() + token,
            )
            .finish()
            .unwrap()
            .send()
            .timeout(Duration::from_secs(30))
            .map_err(actix_web::error::Error::from) // <- convert SendRequestError to an Error
            .and_then(|resp| {
                resp.body().limit(67_108_864).from_err().and_then(|body| {
                    let resp: QuestionResponse = serde_json::from_slice(&body).unwrap();
                    fut_ok(resp.data)
                })
            }),
    )
}
```

Then I use it:

```
let question_ids = vec!["q1", "q2", "q3"];

let mut questions = questions_data().wait().expect("Failed to fetch questions");
let question = question_data("q2")
    .wait()
    .expect("Failed to fetch question");
println!("{:?}", question);

let data = question_ids.map(|id| Box::new(question_data(id)));
```

But I get the error:

```
245 |     let data = question_ids.map(|id| Box::new(question_data(id)));
    |                             ^^^
    |
    = note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::string::String> : futures::Future`
            `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::string::String> : std::iter::Iterator`
            `&mut [std::string::String] : futures::Future`
            `&mut [std::string::String] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

These are similar but does not compile for me, and also I want to use actix-web:

- [Getting multiple URLs concurrently with Hyper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087958/getting-multiple-urls-concurrently-with-hyper)
- [How can I perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests with reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044467/how-can-i-perform-parallel-asynchronous-http-get-requests-with-reqwest)
- [How do I iterate over a Vec of functions returning Futures in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850309/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-vec-of-functions-returning-futures-in-rust)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7wwhhk/patterns_for_processing_a_stream_of_urls/du4jw0t/

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking here. Are you looking for `nums.into_iter().map(|n| make_request(n)).collect()`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I have expaned the question.

Comment: Don't understand your problem.

Comment: If you want to perform all the requests concurrently, you can use [`futures::future::join_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) to combine the individual request futures into a single future returning a vector of results.

Comment: @SvenMarnach and sequentially? Or concurrently but limit number of simultaneous connections?

Comment: @Stargateur I have expaned more

Comment: You need `iter()` or `into_iter()` to map over a vector. There are further problems with your code, but that's the one causing the error message.